# While setting interpretor to python 3.8.2 in django its giving errors such as unable to import django.urls?

Tags: python, django

I am working on Django in VS code. It's giving errors on any Django import (ex unable to import Django.urls) while setting the interpreter to python 3.8. Although when I set the interpreter to python 2.7 the errors are resolved.

I have installed Django in a virtual environment. Please enlighten me why this problem is occurring and will it cause any trouble in the future?

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I have installed Django in a virtual environment. Please enlighten me why this problem is occurring" In your own words, how exactly do you think virtual environments work? Are you expecting each one to have access to every version of Python on your system, somehow? When you created the virtual environment in the first place, did you read the documentation for `venv`?

Comment: @Saurabh Gusain How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the module "`Django`" was not successfully installed in your python3.8 environment, but it was installed in the python2.7 environment.

Since you have python2 and python3, it is recommended that you use pip3 to specify the python version when installing modules using pip.

1.**Solution**: You could try to install the module "`django`" using "`pip3 install django`" in the VSCode terminal. Please note that the pip used is from python3.8. (Check the pip version: "`pip3 --version`")

2.**pip version**: If the pip version is not from python3.8, you can use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VSCode terminal after selecting the python3.8 interpreter, and it will automatically enter the current environment and automatically use pip from the current environment python3.8.

3.**Check**: Use "`pip3 list`" to check whether the module "`Django`" is already installed in the current environment:

[image]